How to get "partially ticked" node in Quasar q-tree

I use quasar tree and it is very useful for my project.
There are three states that are generated: selected, expanded and ticked.
I need to get the partially ticked i undelined in the the picture.
Thanks for any lead.

First, show your code.  Anything ticked in q-tree will be saved to v-model:ticked variable.  Second, it's not clear what "partially ticked" means.  It's not a standard term, so if you could clearly define what you mean that would be helpful.

@yoduh by "partially ticked" they mean a node that has one or more child nodes selected but not all. Basically prompting an "intermediate" state

In the picture, the first and the second items are "partially ticked", the third is not ticked, and the last one is ticked.

The term "partially ticked" refers to the qtree api, in qtree stategy "leaf" mode

I did not find anysolution for this yet. Any other lead?
